# Do I have to follow specifications strictly when using AC?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, rms

I have some device with a connection terminal which can deal with (quote)

**max. 1 A/24 Vac/dc**.

I would like to use it for switching a device with 1A and 12V AC. How are the specifications meant? Is the peak value (since it says *max*) or the RMS current/voltage meant? Since 1A AC will exceed 1A at the peaks I am afraid to break my device if I tried.

**EDIT**

The device is a [Rocom Doormaster Smart 4+n](http://www.rocom-gmbh.com/produkte/abe/adaptere/smarte.htm). On that page it says "Max. load for driver contacts 3 to 5: 24 Vac/dc 1 A" which I am afraid to exceed with my 1A AC at the peaks.

Comment: I would expect it means 1A RMS, but you're right that they don't tell you that explicitly in the datasheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AC is normally measured as the RMS current and voltage.  So if the manufacturer states it can handle 1A at 24V AC, then it can handle up to 1A RMS at up to 24V RMS.

In reality, switching AC is easier than DC as it's less prone to arcing at the terminals when disconnecting.